# render only visible part of list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with a long list (500 items). It takes very long to render on my phone (Galaxy S5). So I thought of implementing something where I draw only the items that are actually visible (and if possible, reusing the dom elements rather than redrawing). Is there a directive that allows this?

Note that this is not exactly infinite scroll since I don't want to lazily load more data. The entire data is there, I just want to show only a sliding window of it (also, infinite scrolling adds more items but doesn't remove those scrolled away, so as I scroll down rendering will become slower and slower)

Comment: How do you do that? I mean drawing only visible items. If you use ng-show or ng-hide, try ng-if. It may improve rendering speed.

Comment: @MajidYaghouti: the point is that once i have the list, some of it is off screen and I want to render only that. I don't want it to be hidden, since that is the case anyways (it is off screen), the point is to create a smaller dom. ng-if may be a solution, if there is a way to give it a condition that shows when an item is off screen.